# Adding UserID to Sentinel analytics query in summarize section

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I am very new to Sentinel and learning, so apologies if this seems very simple.

I am using the Sentinel Analytics rule: "Anomalous login followed by Teams action"
It reacts to Teams admin actions such as members being added to teams. I wish to enrich the output, so in addition to seeing which user added/removed a member, I also want to see the UserID of the newly added or removed user, in the summarize section.

[Picture of the current output, details redacted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYAg9.png)

I have tried altering the query in various places, mainly the "OfficeActivity" section.

But so far no luck, either I get parsing errors, or no results.

> 

```
OfficeActivity

    | where TimeGenerated > ago(queryfrequency)
    | where Operation in~ ("TeamsAdminAction", "MemberAdded", "MemberRemoved", "MemberRoleChanged", "AppInstalled", "BotAddedToTeam")
    | project OperationTimeGenerated = TimeGenerated, UserId = tolower(UserId), Operation, Members
    | join kind = inner(
        userIpDelta
        // Check users with activity from distinct countries
        | where DistinctCountries >= minimumCountries
        // Check users with high IP delta
        | where UserIPDelta >= deltaThreshold
        // Add information about signins and countries
        | join kind = leftouter userIpSignin on UserPrincipalName
        | join kind = leftouter countryPrevalence on Country
        // Check activity that comes from nonprevalent countries
        | where CountryPrevalence < countryPrevalenceThreshold
        | project
            UserPrincipalName,
            SuspiciousIP = IPAddress,
            UserIPDelta,
            SuspiciousSigninCountry = Country,
            SuspiciousCountryPrevalence = CountryPrevalence,
            EventTimes = ListSigninTimeGenerated, 
            MemberAdded = TotalSignin
```

The other section I have been trying in is the "Summarize" section.

```
> summarize arg_max(SigninTimeGenerated, *) by UserPrincipalName,
> SuspiciousIP, OperationTimeGenerated | summarize
>     ActivitySummary =  make_bag(pack(tostring(SigninTimeGenerated), pack("Operation", tostring(Operation), "OperationTime",
> OperationTimeGenerated)))
>     by
>     UserPrincipalName,
>     SuspiciousIP,
>     SuspiciousSigninCountry,
>     SuspiciousCountryPrevalence | extend IPCustomEntity = SuspiciousIP, AccountCustomEntity = UserPrincipalName,
> SuspiciousCountryPrevalence
```

Hope someone can help a new learner, or point me in the direction of some material to assist me.